# Who was this girl that Hulk met after being minimized

Tags: marvel, character-identification

In one old Hulk story (again something I read back in 80's) Hulk was minimized (by the government, if I remember correctly) to atomic scale, or perhaps smaller. In that very small state he stumbled upon a garden-like place where he meets a girl whom he falls in love with.

The girl eventually dies because of something and Hulk is upset about this but soon after that ends up being taken back to "our world".

Who was this girl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be [Jarella](http://marvel.wikia.com/Jarella_%28Earth-616%29), who appears in [The Incredible Hulk #140](http://marvel.wikia.com/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_140).

The issue deals with the Hulk who has been shrunken down for better study.

> Continuing from Avengers #88, the Avengers have just broken into the lair of Psyklop who was attempting to shrink the Hulk down to size for better study. However, while Psyklop was distracted by the Avengers attack, the Hulk is exposed to the shrink ray longer than Psyklop intended, and the Hulk soon finds himself shrunk down to microscopic size.

He meets Jarella.

> Jarella was the princess of the sub-atomic kingdom of K'ai. Though outwardly primitive, this world had remnants of long-forgotten high technology and sorcery. Its people were green-skinned and, for the most part, blond-haired, but otherwise human.

She and the Hulk fall in love, of course, but their love is not meant to be.

> With Visis defeated, the Hulk and Jarella plan to marry. However at that point Psyklops has tracked down the Hulk and arrives on Jarella's micro-world in giant size and seizes the Hulk and takes him back to Earth.

She eventually dies in issue 205.

[image: Jarella]

Comment: That seems a very impractical outfit for sword-fighting.

Comment: Princesses don't sword fight. They've got guards and assassins for that.

Comment: So she's holding the sword for them?

Comment: She's a princess. You don't get to tell her what to do.